# Asynchronous action in other tab

Tags: javascript, tabs, whatsapp

I'm struggling with the following:

I have a website that has a button which is supposed to send a message by whatsapp via whatsapp web

```
<div class="btn-group" id="messages">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="sendWhatsapp('GVALRQ')">
    <i class="fa fa-at"></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;Welcome!
  </button>
  <a id="messageAnchor" href="" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

The onclick event calls the following function:

```
function sendWhatsapp(messageType) {
  let $div = $('<div>');
  $div.load('https://example.com/messagerepository.html #'+messageType, function(){
    let message = $(this).contents().val();
    $('#messageAnchor').attr("href","https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123456&text="+(message));
    $('#messageAnchor')[0].click();
    if (confirm('Were you able to send the message by Whatsapp?')) {
      // do something in case of success
      return true;
    }
    // do something in case of failure
    return false;
  });
}
```

Please don't focus on how that whatsapp api works - it does send the message as it should. It opens the web whatsapp interface prepopulates the message field to be sent to the phone number specified. The user simple has to press 'send', potentially after editing the message. (I'm aware there is better/automated solutions for this, but I need to use this way of working).

My problem is the following: ideally I would have the new whatapp tab tell me (the calling tab, where the button is) that the message has been sent successfully and act acoordingly. I can't do that, since there doesnt seem to be a callback function in the web.whatsapp.com API. So what I'm trying to do is to halt the script until the user has done his message sending in the newly opened tab and returns back to the calling tab and confirms manually that the message was sent ok (or not). The problem with that is that `confirm()` is called after the `click()` so the browser (Chrome) notices that I'm not on the tab where the script is running and throws the following error:

```
A window.confirm() dialog generated by this page was suppressed because this page is not the active tab of the front window. Please make sure your dialogs are triggered by user interactions to avoid this situation. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5140698722467840
```

Any help would be so much appreciated, in descending order or desirability:

- (dreaming) get a callback from the web.whatsapp api ... oh well
- hold a script when navigating away from the tab on which it is running until the user gets back to that tab.
- trick the browser into thinking the user is still on the tab, launch the confirm() and navigate to whatsapp then.